# Is it possible to define several velocity macroses?

Tags: templates, velocity

Is it possible to define several velocity macroses?

Like this:

```
#macro (cap $strIn)
    $strIn.valueOf($strIn.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()$strIn.substring(1)
#end
##
#marco (lowFirst $strIn)
    $strIn.valueOf($strIn.charAt(0)).toLowerCase()$strIn.substring(1)
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to define several Velocity macros.